# How to install the mogenerator in Mac OS 10.14.4

Tags: macos, homebrew, mogenerator

I am not able to install mogenerator after writing in terminal for below command

```
brew install mogenerator
```

and getting error like `-bash: brew: command not found`

can you please provide me step for all process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also getting this type of error mogenerator and solved it by following steps.

1. Open terminal and write command:: /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
2. after doing step 1 if you get error like

> ==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/rm -f /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress
>
> ==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
>
> xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory
>   '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'
>
> Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --switch
>   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

3. In your terminal write command ::   xcode-select --install
4. after doing step no 3 you will get one popUp , so click on install button
5. After completing installation , finally fire command to install mogenerator is. ::  brew install mogenerator

you will not getting error and mogenerator **Installed Successfully**

Reference Link : https://docs.brew.sh/Installation